# Where can I find detailed description of the JSR for the Java Enterprise edition 7 with explanation and details?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsr

I searched the JSR website, but it's pretty random there.  I could not make out much.

Thanks,

Sid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you're likely to get at this juncture is simply [JSR 342](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=342) itself.